# ¿Como asignar valores multiples a mi variable de SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

```
--Para el resultado de esta consulta solo me guarda el ultimo valor y no todos

--Crear la tabla

DECLARE @CargasFinalizadas AS TABLE(

        In_Id_Carga Bigint,
        Ch_Ruc Char(16)
    )


--poblar datos


    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES(1,'123' )
    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (2,'124')
    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas  (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (3,'125')


----declarar variable


    declare @Texto nVARCHAR(max)


--consulta

    select @Texto = cast(in_id_carga as varchar) + ', ' + cast(Ch_Ruc as varchar)  from @CargasFinalizadas
    Select  @Texto
```

Comment: y qué es lo que quieres que guarde?

Comment: Quiero que guarde el concatenado osea 1,123 y 2,124 y asi...

Comment: pero es que debes entender que una variable es eso, algo que guarda un valor, no múltiples (a menos que sea una tabla variable). Así que en efecto sería guardar el concatenado de todas las filas...cuál quieres que sea el separador?, en tu comentario estás usando la letra `y`

Comment: Prueba con algo así `select @Texto = ''; select @Texto = @Texto + cast(in_id_carga as varchar) + ', ' + cast(Ch_Ruc as varchar)  from @CargasFinalizadas;`. Igualmente, te sugiero explicar lo que quieres resolver no como lo quieres hacer, por que es probable que estés apuntando a una solución no del todo adecuada.

Comment: Quiero almacenar la concatenación de un select en una variable

Comment: @PatricioMoracho con su consulta almacene todo en una columna, lo que quisiera es almacenarlo en distintas filas , se podria ello?

Comment: No te entiendo, los datos ya estén en filas separadas en `@CargasFinalizadas` y buscabas concatenar todo en una variable, ¿Que es lo que buscas realmente?

Comment: Los datos me aparecen de la siguiente manera:      1,123  2,124  3,125  con la consulta que me otorgaste quisiera hacer un salto de linea en todo caso para que este separado, he intentado hacer un salto de linea con char(10) pero no funciona en el selcect , como seria ese caso

Comment: Es muy difícil entender lo que preguntás. ¿Estás queriendo retornar todos los registros _en un solo registro, con saltos multilínea_? ¿Por qué no retornarlo como varios registros? Por favor, pulsá en [edit] y sé más específico en tu pregunta, explicando _cuál es el resultado esperado_.

Comment: Agrega un `char(13) + char(10)` y vas a tener el salto de línea habitual en Windows

Comment: Lo que pedis no tiene sentido.. para que queres hacer eso? que estas buscando?

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, por los comentarios y observaciones que han hecho los compañeros creo que una de estas soluciones te puede servir (eso espero).
Son 4 diferentes salida de datos, marque cada uno para que tomes el que te sirve, borra o comenta los ejemplos que no te sirvan de lo contrario no obtendrás el resultado deseado.
Te paso el código:

```
DECLARE @CargasFinalizadas AS TABLE(

        In_Id_Carga Bigint,
        Ch_Ruc Char(16)
    )


--poblar datos


    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES(1,'123' )
    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (2,'124')
    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas  (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (3,'125')


----declarar variable


    declare @Texto nvarchar(500)


--Ejemplo -1
    SELECT cast(In_Id_Carga as varchar) + ', ' + cast(Ch_Ruc as varchar) AS Resultado1 
    FROM @CargasFinalizadas
--Fin

    declare @ID int
    declare Repaso cursor for
    select In_Id_Carga from @CargasFinalizadas


    open Repaso
    fetch next from Repaso
    into @ID
    set @Texto=''
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    begin
--Ejemplo -2
        select cast(In_Id_Carga as varchar) + ', ' + cast(Ch_Ruc as varchar) Resultado2  from @CargasFinalizadas where In_Id_Carga=@ID
--Fin
--Ejemplo -3
        set @Texto = (select cast(In_Id_Carga as varchar) + ', ' + cast(Ch_Ruc as varchar) Resultado3  from @CargasFinalizadas where In_Id_Carga=@ID)
        print @Texto
--Fin
--Ejemplo 4-
        select @Texto+= cast(In_Id_Carga as varchar) + ', ' + cast(Ch_Ruc as varchar)  from @CargasFinalizadas where In_Id_Carga=@ID
--Fin
        Fetch next from Repaso
        into @ID
    end
    close Repaso
    deallocate Repaso


    select @Texto as Resultado4
```

El Ejemplo 1 se muestra así:

[image: El Ejemplo 1 se muestra así:]

EL Ejemplo 2 así:

[image: EL Ejemplo 2 así:]

EL Ejemplo 3 así:

[image: EL Ejemplo 3 así:]

El ejemplo 4 así:

[image: El ejemplo 4 así:]

Answer (score 0):

El poblado de datos lo puedes reducir a esto

```
    INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (1,'123'), 
                                                               (2,'124'),
                                                               (3,'125')
```

Comment: Esto es lo mismo que esta en la pregunta.. que quisiste responder?